# My generated image map is not working

Tags: html, imagemap

I've had a few shots at creating an image map with various generators.

None have worked.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pn9j3sux/) of my code.

```
<img src="http://www.kidstart.co.uk/resources/Christmas2014/img/PresentTree.png" usemap="#xmastree" width="184" height="871" alt="" />
```

Comment: JSFiddle link links to home page!

Comment: Yeah, just been trying to edit. Should work now. :)